# Using a service class with asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm writing a web app (asp.net core, mvc), and at the moment all of my code is in controllers. I want to move some of it into service classes, to ease with re-use of code, and tidy up my controller classes a little.

The problem is, when I try do this, I keep getting the error  'Cannot access a disposed object.'

It seems that the second time I try to use a database access class (DBcontext or userManager), the class (or something else) is disposed.

A sample of my code is below. I have removed some bits for brevity sake (the removed bits are mostly irrelevant).

Firstly, the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyProject.Data;
using MyProject.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using MyProject.Models.Api;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MyProject.Services;

namespace MyProject.ApiControllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Migration")]
    public class MigrationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private InitialMigrationService _initialMigrationService;

        public MigrationController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _initialMigrationService = new InitialMigrationService(userManager, roleManager, context, configuration);
        }

        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("GetDumpData")]
        public async Task<bool> GetDumpData([FromBody] ApiDataDumpInfo apiDataDumpInfo)
        {
            // I have removed some code here to download a file into dumpBytes (byte array). This works fine

            Models.InitialMigration.DataDump dataDump = Models.InitialMigration.DataDump.DeserialiseFromByteArray(dumpBytes);
            _initialMigrationService.MigrateDataDump(dataDump);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

And the service class (and interface):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyProject.Data;
using MyProject.Models;
using MyProject.Models.InitialMigration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace MyProject.Services
{
    public class InitialMigrationService : IInitialMigrationService
    {
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private IConfiguration _configuration;

        public InitialMigrationService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, ApplicationDbContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public bool MigrateDataDump(DataDump dump)
        {
            MigrateUserSetup(dump);
            return true;
        }
        private void MigrateUserSetup(DataDump dump)
        {
            dump.UserSetupList.ForEach(u => u.Accounts = true);
            dump.UserSetupList.ForEach(async delegate (DDUserSetup u)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Email))
                    return;
                var swUser = _context.SoftwareUser
                    .SingleOrDefault(du => du.OldID == u.ID);
                if (swUser == null)
                {
                    _context.SoftwareUser.Add(new Models.SoftwareUser
                    {
                        Name = u.Name
                        // Have left out lots of other fields being copied over
                    });
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    swUser = _context.SoftwareUser
                        .SingleOrDefault(du => du.OldID == u.ID);
                    string userID = await EnsureUser(u.Password, u.Email, swUser.ID);
                    await EnsureRole(userID, ConstantData.ConstUserRole);
                }
            });

        }
        private async Task<string> EnsureUser(string testUserPw, string userName, int? SoftwareUserId)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            IdentityResult result = null;
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = userName, SoftwareUserID = SoftwareUserId, Email = userName };
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testUserPw))
                    result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                else
                    result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, testUserPw); // This is the line I get the error on.
            }
            return user.Id;
        }
        private async Task<IdentityResult> EnsureRole(string uid, string role)
        {
            try
            {
                IdentityResult IR = null;

                if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
                {
                    IR = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
                }

                var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(uid);

                IR = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);

                return IR;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IInitialMigrationService
    {
        bool MigrateDataDump(DataDump dump);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've searched for a specific example of how this sort of thing is meant to be structured, but couldnt find much beyond using an interface (which doesnt seem to help).

Thanks.

--- EDIT ---
As per Camilos suggestion, I have made the following changes:

```
MigrationController now starts like this:

    public class MigrationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private IInitialMigrationService _initialMigrationService;

        public MigrationController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration, IInitialMigrationService initialMigrationService)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _initialMigrationService = initialMigrationService;
        }
```

And made this addition to the Startup.ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IInitialMigrationService, InitialMigrationService>();
```

But I still get the same error.

----- EDIT 2 ----
I now suspect the issue is with running Async methods. It seems that running an Asynch method makes the object disposed the next time I try to use it.

For example, in the block below (for my "MigrateUserSetup" method), I changed "SaveChanges" to "SaveChangesAsync", and the next time the dbcontext is used, I get the disposed error:

```
private  void MigrateUserSetup(DataDump dump)
{
    dump.UserSetupList.ForEach(async delegate (DDUserSetup u)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Email))
            return;
        var swUser = _context.SoftwareUser
            .SingleOrDefault(du => du.OldID == u.ID);
        if (swUser == null)
        {
            _context.SoftwareUser.Add(new Models.SoftwareUser
            {
                Name = u.Name,
                // Migrate a bunch of fields
            });
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // This was previously just "SaveChanges()", not Async
            swUser = _context.SoftwareUser
                .SingleOrDefault(du => du.OldID == u.ID); // Now I get the disposed object error here
            string userID = await EnsureUserAsync(u.Password, u.Email, swUser.ID);
            await EnsureRole(userID, ConstantData.ConstUserRole);
        }
    });

}
```

---- EDIT 3 ----

I've finally got it working. I ended up replacing the user setup loop from a "ForEach" to a "for" loop, as below:

Original "ForEach" loop:

```
    dump.UserSetupList.ForEach(async delegate (DDUserSetup u)
    {
```

New "For" loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dump.UserSetupList.Count; i++)
    {
        var u = dump.UserSetupList[i];
```

I'm not sure how this makes such a big difference, or if this is really a desirable solution, but might give a bit more of a clue as to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
_initialMigrationService = new InitialMigrationService(userManager, roleManager, context, configuration);
```

is not correct. If you look at all of the previous lines in that constructor, there's not another `new` there, and there's a reason for that, called Dependency Injection.

When you want to create your own services, you register them up on the DI container that ASP.NET Core provides:

```
public
{
    ...

    services.AddScoped<IInitialMigrationService, InitialMigrationService>();

    ...
}
```

And then you ask for a new instance of that service to be created *for you*:

```
public MigrationController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration, IInitialMigrationService initialMigrationService)
{
    _context = context;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _roleManager = roleManager;
    _configuration = configuration;
    _initialMigrationService = initialMigrationService;
}
```

In a not-so-unrelated note, beware that injecting `IConfiguration` can lead to huge wastes of RAM. You should follow the Configuration/Options approaches instead.

Comment: Thanks - I tried this without success. Bit of detail in my original post.
Not sure about the Configurtion/Options approach. I guess I'll do some searching on this later.

Comment: I'm going to assume I was doing two things wrong - not using dependency injection, and using a List.Foreach. I have it working - thanks for your help.